# Card is taking all the vertical space in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have used the Card widget to show in the list but the card is taking up all the vertical space like this.

[image: Card with debug paint]

So it makes listview worse and shows something like this.

[image: Card with listView]

I have tried changing the mainAxisAlignment to max and min but it didn't work out pretty well.

Here is the code that I have written for the card:

```dart
Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(cardMargin, 0, cardMargin, cardWidth),
        elevation: 5,
        child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              height: cardHeight,
              width: cardWidth / 2,
              child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/demo.jpg"))),
          new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              height: cardHeight,
              width: cardWidth / 2,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        height: cardHeight / 2,
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text("Chevrolet Camero 2015",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                                    child: Text("121,000",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                                Row(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text("AED",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                              fontSize: 10))
                                    ])
                              ]))
                        ])),
                    Container(
                        child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text("Lot #",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 11))),
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text("123456",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                              ])),
                          Flexible(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text("Bids",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 11))),
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text("37",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                              ])),
                          Flexible(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text("Time left",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 11))),
                                Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text("03:15:32",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
                              ]))
                        ]))
                  ])))
        ]));
```

Here is the main page:

```dart
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
      new Stack(children: <Widget>[
        new CustomAppBar("Cars & Machinery"),
        new Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: new AppBarMenu()))
      ]),
      new Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text("Scroll down to Search",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12))),
     // new CarItem()
      new Expanded(
          child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 2,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                return new CarItem();
              }))
    ]);
```

I want the card to show properly on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with below line which you have written for Card:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(cardMargin, 0, cardMargin, cardWidth),
```

4th param stands for bottom margin and in that you gave value of cardWidth instead of margin. Check with updating value as per below.:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(cardMargin, 0, cardMargin, cardMargin),
```